# Proving some topological properties of Path Components of $\mathbb{R}^2 - J$ where $J$ is a Jordan curve(2).

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, category-theory, path-connected

Let $X = \mathbb{R}^2 - J$ where $J$ is a Jordan curve. We know that $X = \bigcup_{i \in \mathcal{I}}$ where the subsets $U_{i}$ are the path components of $X.$ These subsets are pairwise disjoint. (we do not assume that the topology on $X$ is the disjoint union topology)

A Jordan curve in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is the image $J$ of an injective continuous function $w : S^1 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2.$ If $J$ is a Jordan curve with the inclusion map $j : J \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2,$ then there is the following commutative diagram > $$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
S^1 @>{w}>> \mathbb{R}^2\\
@VVV @VVV \\
J @>{j}>> \mathbb{R}^2
\end{CD}$$

> The first vertical arrow should have the map $\bar{\omega}$ on it. Also,I am not skillful in drawing commutative diagrams this is why I draw $\mathbb{R}^2$ 2 times because I do not know how to draw one curved arrow coming out of $J$ going directly to $\mathbb{R}^2$ my bad.

Now using the compactness of $S^1$ and the Hausdorffitude of $\mathbb{R}^2,$ we can see that $\bar{\omega} : S^1 \rightarrow J$ is a homeomorphism.

having already knew the answers of those questions with the help of @jgon:

$(a)$ Show that $X$ is open in  $\mathbb{R}^2.$

$(b)$ Show that each $U_{i}$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^2.$

I was given a hint to assume (without proving it) that every open ball $B_{r}(\mathbf{x})$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is convex.

**My questions are:**

$(c)$ Show that $J\subseteq B_{R}(\mathbf{0})$ for some $R.$

$(d)$ Show that every path component of $X$ except one is contained in $B_{R}(\mathbf{0})$ (where $R$ is the same number as in part $(c)$).

for this question I was given the following hint: think in terms of the equivalence relation $\sim$ defined by $x \sim y$ iff there is a path from $x$ to $y.$

Still I am unable to answer $(c)$ & $(d)$ could anyone give me a hint for answering them please?

Comment: Is there any reason to post the same question again?

Comment: No it is not the same questions .... I am asking different ones @HanulJeon

Comment: (c) hint: compactness

Comment: @JohnPalmieri yes I know that $J$ is compact  .... but why the center of the ball must be 0? how will I include this in my proof?

Comment: @Smart20 $J$ is compact and therefore bounded. Thus, for any $x$ there is $R>0$ such that $J\subseteq B_R(x)$. This applies to $x=0$ as well.

Comment: @freakish what about my other question?

Comment: @Smart20 If $C_1,C_2$ are two path components of $X$ not fully contained in $B_R(0)$, then there is $x_1\in C_1\backslash B_R(0)$ and $x_2\in C_2\backslash B_R(0)$. So you have two points outside of $B_R(0)$ and so they can be connected via a path. Therefore $C_1=C_2$. Meaning at most 1 path component of $X$ can be outside of $B_R(0)$. The existance of such component is easy to determine: it is a path component of any point outside of $B_R(0)$.

Comment: Why are you proving existence and uniqueness @freakish does the statement of the question requires this?

Comment: @Smart20 Yes. "every component except one is contained in $B_R(0)$" can be rewritten as "there exists exactly one component $C$ such that for any other component $C'$ we have $C'\subseteq B_R(0)$".

Comment: Why we are sure that $x_{1}$ and $x_{2}$ can be connected by a path? is that because now we are dividing $X$ into 2 parts $B_{R}(0)$ and $X\ B_{R}(0)$ and $X$ should be the union of its path components? @freakish

Comment: @Smart20 try drawing a picture. You have two points outside of a circle. How can you connect them by a path totally outside of the circle? Since the circle is centered at $0$ then you can use a rotation and a straight line afterwards.